# Group by within a function does not properly group by

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to create a function that could allow me to quickly create a pivot table based on a number of factors. However, every time I run it, the function doesn't drop the index, which in turn does not aggregate data.

for example Here is one of the dframes I've been working with

```
     User_ID    Trans_Type  Date      Revenue    Cohort    Month
0   958507335   Purchase    2013-02-01  22.0    2013-02   2013-02
1   77396089    Purchase    2013-02-01  50.0    2013-02   2013-04
2   168623910   Sale        2013-02-01  20.0    2013-02   2013-02
3   124390583   Sale        2013-02-01  53.0    2013-02   2013-03
4   312221573   Sale        2013-02-01  160.0   2013-02   2013-04
5   767171090   Sale        2013-02-01  56.0    2013-02   2013-04
6   328835282   Sale        2013-02-01  76.0    2013-02   2013-02
7   289850608   Sale        2013-02-01  27.0    2013-02   2013-06
8   926145734   Sale        2013-02-01  16.0    2013-02   2013-02
9   950422305   Sale        2013-02-01  49.0    2013-02   2013-04
```

Basically, there are two transaction types. Sale and Purchase.

Here is the function I have been using to create a pivot table from it.

```
x = 'Sale'
df = df.set_index('User_ID', inplace=True)

def LTV_calc_(df):
    df1 = df[df['Transaction_Type'] == x]
    #Convert to a pivot table
    df2 = df1.groupby(['Cohort','Month'])
    df3 = df2.agg({'User_ID': ['count'],
               'Revenue': ['sum']})

    return df3
Sales = df.groupby(level=0).apply(LTV_calc_)
```

Now when I run the Sales DF, it comes out something like this:

```
                      User_ID Revenue
                      count   sum
        Cohort  Month       
16940   2013-02 2013-02  1  59.0
16941   2013-02 2013-02  1  62.0
16942   2013-04 2013-04  1  288.0
16943   2013-02 2013-02  1  33.0
16944   2013-05 2013-05  1  14.0
16945   2013-03 2013-03  1  0.0
```

Whenever I run the code without a function, it correctly produces this:

```
               User_ID  Rev/Payout
               count    sum
Cohort  Month       
2013-02 2013-02  293   8449.0
        2013-03  41    1208.0
        2013-04  52    1708.0
        2013-05  55    2469.0
        2013-06  62    2911.0
```

I've had this problem a couple other times.

Anyone know what I a doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by `run the code without a function`?

Comment: Creating the desired dataframe without a function. As in taking the time to manually create a pivot table for both sales and purchases. In this example it wouldn't be too painstaking since I only need 2 pivot tables, but some of my other files i would need to do the same thing 20 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call groupby().apply(), just call the function to do the computation.

```
import pandas as pd

x = 'Sale'

def LTV_calc_(df):
    return df[df['Trans_Type'] == x].groupby(['Cohort','Month']).agg({'User_ID': ['count'],
               'Revenue': ['sum']})

Sales = LTV_calc_(df)

df
Out[79]: 
     User_ID Trans_Type        Date  Revenue   Cohort    Month
0  958507335   Purchase  2013-02-01     22.0  2013-02  2013-02
1   77396089   Purchase  2013-02-01     50.0  2013-02  2013-04
2  168623910       Sale  2013-02-01     20.0  2013-02  2013-02
3  124390583       Sale  2013-02-01     53.0  2013-02  2013-03
4  312221573       Sale  2013-02-01    160.0  2013-02  2013-04
5  767171090       Sale  2013-02-01     56.0  2013-02  2013-04
6  328835282       Sale  2013-02-01     76.0  2013-02  2013-02
7  289850608       Sale  2013-02-01     27.0  2013-03  2013-06
8  926145734       Sale  2013-02-01     16.0  2013-03  2013-02
9  950422305       Sale  2013-02-01     49.0  2013-04  2013-04

Sales
Out[80]: 
                User_ID Revenue
                  count     sum
Cohort  Month                  
2013-02 2013-02       2    96.0
        2013-03       1    53.0
        2013-04       2   216.0
2013-03 2013-02       1    16.0
        2013-06       1    27.0
2013-04 2013-04       1    49.0
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you don't understand my answer look at the output of df at the bottom. This is the modified df that I used to check the code. Sales, the output of the function has the correct sum of Sale transactions (20+53+160) and the count of user IDs is also correct - 3. There is no need to set User_ID as the index of the data frame - in fact this is a bug.

Comment: Hey sorry, I screwed up there. I re-edited the dataset to include more months and cohorts than 2013-02. The problem I was trying to iterate was that the function essentially treats the month & cohort as the same, and aggregates everyone in 2013-02.  Really the month column is a retention tracker for a specific cohort. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you look at the updated output. Does it look all right?

Comment: Yup, that looks right! How did you get it to do that? I still have the same problem.

Comment: If you were able to get that with that code, then I am guessing its something on my end. Thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome. If you still have a problem, copy everything from this answer in a new file and try it again. It might be worth clearing all variables from memory. All you need is to load the data frame from the example and run the lines from the answer. There are a few mistakes in your code, so it will help if you avoid mixing the codes.

Comment: It's probably that. I had to tamper around with original data frame to get the one I presented here. But it doesn't matter, this is a great framework to work off and that's what I needed. (this dataset was only a sample.)